# Calling a function on an android thread that is already running? Write on the same thread that is listening for Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

The following problem is about reading and writing on the same thread that is used for handling a bluetooth socket in android.

I don't understand how it is possible to call the write function on a thread that is already running. The code works perfectly, but I cannot understand why.

In the following code from the android dev website, thread seems to keep listening in an infinite loop. Furthermore the `socket.getInputStream()` function is a blocking call meaning that it waits until there is data to read before that line executes. I don't understand then how, when the `ConnectedThread.write()` function is called, that the function is called instantly. If the thread is already busy listening for incoming data, how can it also `write()`? Shouldn't it complete the `run()` function before it can `write()`? And the way the code is written it doesn't seem like the `run()`function will ever finish executing because it is in an infinite loop.

```
// Code
public class MyBluetoothService {
    private static final String TAG = "MY_APP_DEBUG_TAG";
    private Handler mHandler; // handler that gets info from Bluetooth service

    // Defines several constants used when transmitting messages between the
    // service and the UI.
    private interface MessageConstants {
        public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 0;
        public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 1;
        public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 2;

        // ... (Add other message types here as needed.)
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        private byte[] mmBuffer; // mmBuffer store for the stream

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams; using temp objects because
            // member streams are final.
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating input stream", e);
            }
            try {
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating output stream", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int numBytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream.
                    numBytes = mmInStream.read(mmBuffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
                    Message readMsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(
                            MessageConstants.MESSAGE_READ, numBytes, -1,
                            mmBuffer);
                    readMsg.sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device.
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);

                // Share the sent message with the UI activity.
                Message writtenMsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(
                        MessageConstants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, mmBuffer);
                writtenMsg.sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when sending data", e);

                // Send a failure message back to the activity.
                Message writeErrorMsg =
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(MessageConstants.MESSAGE_TOAST);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("toast",
                        "Couldn't send data to the other device");
                writeErrorMsg.setData(bundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(writeErrorMsg);
            }
        }

        // Call this method from the main activity to shut down the connection.
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the connect socket", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code works as expected, but I don't understand why.

Comment: do you have the link to the android developer website where you got this code from?

Comment: Yes. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#ManageAConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a little confusion around some concepts. I'll try to do some clarification.

> the socket.getInputStream() function is a blocking call

It's just a getter, it doesn't block. `socket.getInputStream().read()` is the blocker one.

> I don't understand then how, when the ConnectedThread.write() function is called, that the function is called instantly.

`write()` is probably called by another thread. In this case, think of `ConnectedThread` as a common object like any other.

### EDIT

Here's a code example that illustrates the new thread running alongside the thread already present.

```java
// At this point you have one thread (there may be more,
// but suppose it's only one).
// The thread is executing the code below.

ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
connectedThread.start();

// Now you have two threads running simultaneously.
// The new thread is doing whatever the run() method defined in
// ConnectedThread,
// that is that infinite loop with read() calls.
// But this thread goes on.

connectedThread.write();

// The write() call above is executed in this thread,
// which has nothing to do with
// the run() defined in ConnectedThread.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However in my usage of the ConnectedThread, the same ConnectedThread object is used to read and write from a given BluetoothSocket. So if I am communicating with multiple devices, I have exactly one ConnectedThread per BluetoothSocket. That's why I am confused as to how the write() function is called instantly.

Comment: @Suhaib it seems you're having trouble understanding how the threads and objects interact. I added an example. If you have trouble seeing how multiple threads run, I'll try to help with that

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand how it is possible to call the write function on a thread that is already running...

You aren't "calling it on a *thread*." You are calling it on a `Thread`.  A `Thread` is an object in your program with methods that your code can call in exactly the same way that it calls the methods of any other object.  The `Thread` class has one very special instance method, `t.start()` which creates a new operating system *thread*, but otherwise, it's just like any other Java class.

The `t.start()` method creates a new *thread*. The new thread calls your `Thread` object's `run()` method, and then after `run()` returns or throws an exception, the new thread dies.

You haven't showed us the other code that calls `write()`, but it's probably just as @nandsito said: Some other *thread* in your code is calling that method on your `Thread` instance.